# Objective C - underscore needed without @synthesize?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I get an error from this method, i have an imageView property linked to the header file from my storyboard, but it works only when i use the _imageView instead of imageView. The original code uses the imageView version without underscore, but it has a @synthesize imageView line under the @implementation. Do i need the underscore because of the lack of @synthesize?

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
NSDictionary *filteredDictionary = [filterNames objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
imageView.image = [filteredDictionary objectForKey:@"filteredImage"];
```

Comment: What version of Xcode are you using? In old versions you had to `@synthesize` but in current versions you only need it for non-default behaviour. Do not use `_imageView` or `@synthesize` except in abnormal situations. Use `self.imageView` instead. The underscore is there to discourage you from accessing the variable that way.

Comment: I'm using the newest version, I'll try the self.imageView, because the underscore version works without errors, but nothing appears in the simulator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Apple flip flopped on this.

If you add the default `@synthesize:`:

```
@synthesize propertyName;
```

Then the instance variable will be called `propertyName`. If you omit the `@synthesize` and allow it to be inferred implicitly, the instance variable will be called `_propertyName`.

I guess one internal school of thought ended up winning over another.

Comment: I think they just changed their minds, but didn't want to break old code that used `@synthesize`.

Answer (score 1):

In the current version of Xcode it does the @synthesize for you behind the scenes.   But in doing so forces you to use the underscore. It is similar to you using @synthesize imageView = _imageView. So if you don't synthesize use the underscore.

Answer (score 1):

There are two possible variants to access instance variable:

1. By using property. In this case you should use `self.imageView`
2. By direct access to the variable. Code for access depends on using `@synthesize` or not.
   If you **don't use** `@synthesize` then compiler automatically creates instance variable for you with underscore: `_imageView`.
   If you **use** `@synthesize imageView` or `@synthesize imageView = imageView` then you should access instance variable by calling: `imageView` without underscore.